# Decrypt with public key, openssl_public_decrypt like

Tags: c#, openssl, rsa

I've a server that sends me an encrypted message.
This message is encrypted with the server's private key and I'm trying to decrypt it using the public key.
The verify method doesn't fit my needs because it returns true or false.

I found out that OpenSSL has a method called openssl_public_decrypt.
I tried to use OpenSSL .Net wrapper and didn't manage to get it to work.

So I'm asking here if there's another library that can Decrypt with public key and return the decrypted message, like OpenSSL's one ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It sounds like some ad-hoc attempt at using RSA for message signature with recovery. You say "it didn't work" but you don't give any details. Are you using the "NO PADDING" option, for example?

Comment: I just said that I didn't manage to get it to work. There are 2 DLLs to add to the working directory or path and I tried both of them without any result. I can't load the library, dependancies are missing. And even if I could get it to work, there are too many constraints (Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package must be installed, both DLLs must be joined to the executable, etc...).

Comment: @Moonlight-Angel - After dealing with this issue myself, I am actually finding it easier to simply compile php (the whole library) into my application, just to run the WORKING command for public key decryption of data encoded with a private key ----  do not be fooled by the 99% online,  private keys are MEANT to encrypt and kept under lock/key, while public is meant to read the data, but not be able to recreate/forge the encryption used with a private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do the crypto yourself, you may want to have a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706744/706119

i wrote that for another question, but you can probably use it in your scenario

it's a small implementation of RSA using Bigint ... you will have to deal with the padding yourself, but you can decrypt that way...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the padding is PKCS#1. So if I understood correctly, the method rsaOperation is for both encryption and decryption ? And the "strip PKCS#1_V1.5 padding" comment would be good enough to handle my padding after decryption ? If so, thank you very much :).

Comment: @Moonlight-Angel ... you are right about the rsaOperation function ... about the padding, i didn't really read the specs so, no guarantee here, but it worked for 100 test cases with random data encrypted by the .net rsacryptoserviceprovider class and decrypted with that code ...

Answer (score 0):

Private key is usually intended for decryption, but in the situation you described, another approach is used. Server decrypts data with private key, and then sends it to the client. That way, when client encrypts the received message with public key, it gets the original data.

If you are developing server and client, you should try this approach. And if the server belongs to someone else, they probably use it already.

As for implementation, you can try built-in .Net classes for assymetric encryption. Assuming server uses RSA algorithm for encryption, you can use RSACryptoServiceProvider class.

Comment: As you said, the server belongs to someone else and they don't do it this way for sure.