# How to encrypt a section of an App.config file using a provided RSA public key

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, app-config

I have someone's public key as a string:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>publickeyhere</Modulus>
  <Exponent>AAAA</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I also have an app.config file and I'm trying to encrypt the appSettings section of it using the public key. I'm doing it like this

```
var publicKeyXml = @"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>publickeyhere</Modulus><Exponent>AAAA</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
{
    ExeConfigFilename = "app.config"
};

var config = ConfigurationManager
    .OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    try
    {
        rsa.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);

        // Now use the public key to encrypt how?
        config.AppSettings.SectionInformation
            .ProtectSection("RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider");
        config.SaveAs($"app.encrypted.config");
    }
    finally
    {
        rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    }
}
```

How can I tell it that to do the encryption, it should use the public key and not one from the current machine it's running on?

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt public key? Should not it be by definition accessible for everyone?

Comment: Sorry, I've not been clear. In RSA (and I'm no expert) I believe you use a public key to encrypt data, then the owner of the key uses their private key to decrypt the data. That's what I want to do, I want to use it to encrypt the data, then give it to them.

Comment: Ok, you got it right.

Comment: You can also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702718/public-key-encryption-with-rsacryptoserviceprovider

Comment: @Nick yes, thanks, I've read that page, but I'm not trying to rewrite all the encryption stuff myself. .NET Framework can already encrypt app.config files using `config.AppSettings.SectionInformation
            .ProtectSection("RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider");` but I just don't know how to specify the public key I want it to use. If the encryption is being done remotely to have the app deployed to a server I need to use the server's public key, not my machine's.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.protectedconfigurationprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2)? It shows how to create and use keys.